# Get content of object XMLHttpRequest with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to debug a problem with some jquery/ajax form stuff, and I need to access the content of the XMLHttpRequest object being passed to my error() function - what's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest(object).responseText try this.

Comment: have you tried var_dump?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Apurv - jackpot! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome (or Firebug, or whatever), if you set a breakpoint, you will be able to inspect local variables. So if you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the error function it will stop the code and you will be able to inspect the jQuery object. You can also use the Javascript statement [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) as the first one in the callback.

Another way is, at the beginning of the error function, to write the object to `console.log(error)`. The Chrome console is smart and will let you browse the object. This is the signature of the error callback:

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```